# Create event log list from tkinter button presses

Tags: python, list, tkinter

This is my first venture into tkinter programming, so far I have the following code that increases or decreases a number by pressing either button. As you may notice I have started adding an update definition that I'd like to update a results table with the label value each time a button is pressed. I've recently found the lambda expression to add two commands to each button press but can't find an example to build the list:

```
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()

def increase():
    value = int(lbl_value["text"])
    lbl_value["text"] = f"{value + 1}"
    
def decrease():
    value = int(lbl_value["text"])
    lbl_value["text"] = f"{value - 1}"
    
def update():
    result_table = []    

window.rowconfigure(0, minsize = 100, weight = 1)
window.columnconfigure([0,1,2], minsize = 100, weight = 1)

btn_decrease = tk.Button(master = window, text = "-", command = lambda:[decrease(), update()], bg = 'red', fg = 'white')
btn_decrease.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

lbl_value = tk.Label(master = window, text = "0")
lbl_value.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

btn_increase = tk.Button(master = window, text = "+", command = lambda:[increase(), update()], bg = 'green', fg = 'white')
btn_increase.grid(row = 0, column = 2, sticky = "nsew")


window.mainloop()
, bg = 'black', fg = 'white')
btn_decrease.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nsew")

lbl_value = tk.Label(master = window, text = "0")
lbl_value.grid(row = 0, column = 1)

btn_increase = tk.Button(master = window, text = "+", command = increase, bg = 'red', fg = 'white')
btn_increase.grid(row = 0, column = 2, sticky = "nsew")

window.mainloop()
```

I'd like to add a graph of the count to the display ultimately. Any help greatly appreciated.
Matt

Comment: Do you only want one element or all the elements?

Comment: _"I've recently found the lambda expression to add two commands to each button press but can't find an example to build the list:"_ I recommend against that practice. Create a function that will call your other commands. Complex lambdas are difficult to debug. If you always want to call `update` when calling `increase` or `descrease`, just call it from those functions.

Comment: I'd like to log the count that appears in the label element each time either of the buttons is pressed

Comment: Bryan Oakley, you're absolutely right. I added   result_table.append(lbl_value['text'])   to each of the functions and it seems to register the history of values so a huge thanks for the solution. I'll keep experimenting now my motivation has been thoroughly restored...